# Mysql Views issue ( repeated )

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to extract a report using MySQL views, but a new row is repeated for each user as shown in the following image

could you please help me to rewrite this query to resolve this issue ?

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS adminExportFromDate;
  DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS adminExportToDate;
  create function adminExportFromDate() returns DATETIME DETERMINISTIC NO SQL return @adminExportFromDate;
  create function adminExportToDate() returns DATETIME DETERMINISTIC NO SQL return @adminExportToDate;

  create or replace view admin_export as
     Select  admin.id as id ,CONCAT(admin.first_name," ",admin.last_name) as Name ,
             count(DISTINCT `all_jobs`.`id`)AS all_jobs_count,
             sum( case when `all_jobs`.job_status_id = 25 then 1 else 0 end ) as canceled_jobs_count,
             sum( case when `all_jobs`.job_status_id in (31,30,3) then 1 else 0 end ) as finished_jobs_count,
             0 as deleted_jobs_count
         From admin
             INNER  JOIN job all_jobs on all_jobs.created_by_id = admin.id and all_jobs.created_by_level = \'admin\'
             and `all_jobs`.`request_date` > AdminExportFromDate() AND `all_jobs`.`request_date` < AdminExportToDate()
      group by admin.id

      UNION ALL

  select admin.id,CONCAT(admin.first_name," ",admin.last_name) as Name,
  0 AS all_jobs_count,
  0 as canceled_jobs_count,
  0 as finished_jobs_count,
  count( deleted_log.id ) as deleted_jobs_count

  From admin INNER JOIN deleted_log
      on deleted_log.`type` LIKE \'job\' and data RLIKE CONCAT(\'"created_by_level":"admin","created_by_id":"\',`admin`.`id`,\'"\') and `deleted_log`.`created_at` > AdminExportFromDate() AND `deleted_log`.`created_at` < AdminExportToDate()
      group by admin.id
```

And this is the result of view :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UNION ALL`/`UNION` creates multiple rows.  You want to bring the rows together.  That usually involves a `JOIN` instead.

In this case, I think something like this does what you want:

```
Select a.id as id, CONCAT(a.first_name, ' ', a.last_name) as Name,
       coalesce(j.all_jobs_count, 0) as all_jobs_count,
       coalesce(j.canceled_jobs_count, 0) as canceled_jobs_count,
       coalesce(j.finished_jobs_count, 0) as finished_jobs_count,
       coalesce(0, deleted_jobs_count) as deleted_jobs_count
From admin a left join
     (select j.created_by_id,
             count(distinct j.id) as all_jobs_count,
             sum(  j.job_status_id = 25 ) as canceled_jobs_count,
             sum( j.job_status_id in (31, 30, 3) ) as finished_jobs_count
      from job j
      where j.created_by_level = \'admin\' and
            j.request_date > AdminExportFromDate() and
            j.request_date < AdminExportToDate()
      group by j.created_by_id
     ) j
     on j.created_by_id = a.id left join
     (select dl.data, count(*) as deleted_jobs_count
      from deleted_log dl
      where dl.`type` LIKE \'job\' and
            dl.`created_at` > AdminExportFromDate() AND
            dl.`created_at` < AdminExportToDate()
      group by dl.data
     ) dl
     on dl.data RLIKE CONCAT(\'"created_by_level":"admin", "created_by_id":"\', a.id, \'"\')
```

EDIT:

The above obviously won't work for a view in MySQL (arggh!).  Subqueries in the `from` clause can be used instead:

```
Select a.id as id, CONCAT(a.first_name, ' ', a.last_name) as Name,
       (select count(*)
        from jobs j
        where j.created_by_id = a.id and
              j.created_by_level = \'admin\' and
              j.request_date > AdminExportFromDate() and
              j.request_date < AdminExportToDate()
       )  as all_jobs_count,
       (select count(*)
        from jobs j
        where j.created_by_id = a.id and
              j.created_by_level = \'admin\' and
              j.request_date > AdminExportFromDate() and
              j.request_date < AdminExportToDate() and
              j.job_status = 25
       )  as canceled_jobs_count,
       (select count(*)
        from jobs j
        where j.created_by_id = a.id and
              j.created_by_level = \'admin\' and
              j.request_date > AdminExportFromDate() and
              j.request_date < AdminExportToDate() and
              j.job_status in (31, 30, 3)
       ) as finished_jobs_count,
     (select count(*) as deleted_jobs_count
      from deleted_log dl
      where dl.data rlike concat(\'"created_by_level":"admin", "created_by_id":"\', a.id, \'"\') and
            dl.`type` like \'job\' and
            dl.`created_at` > AdminExportFromDate() AND
            dl.`created_at` < AdminExportToDate()
     ) as deleted_jobs_count
From admin a
```